# Texture Packer pvr.ccz files

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

Can Texture Packer's pvr.ccz files be used in a non cocos2d app? I'd like to use them with core animation. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Out of the box? No.

You can write your own .pvr.ccz texture loader respectively adapt the .pvr.ccz texture loading code from cocos2d. The key part really is just the compression format (ccz) which uses the zlib compression provided by the iOS/Mac SDK. After inflating the compressed file, you end up with a regular PVR texture that you can use in Core Animation.

Comment: What should I use to see a pvr.ccz file?